# Get the data from a protected Meta data object in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get the value of `ntva` from this Object but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
Meta_data Object ( [current_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 99769 [key] => ntva [value] => SRTTE ) [data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 99769 [key] => ntva [value] => SRTTE ) );

Foreach ($data->current_data as $key => $value){ 
echo $key.', value'.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

This foreach does not show me anything.

This object comes from WooCommerce (e-commerce wordpress plugin) ORDER data array. I need the `ntva` value to display it in PDF invoice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/dc7aa3069466f1b7e23fd7ef468760a6a9ddd241/includes/class-wc-meta-data.php#L87), `WC_Meta_Data` has a getter `__get`, so you will be able to access it like:

`$data->key` which will output `ntva`

Or use the [get_data()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/dc7aa3069466f1b7e23fd7ef468760a6a9ddd241/includes/class-wc-meta-data.php#L114) method:

```
foreach ($data->get_data() as $key => $value){ 
    echo $key.', value'.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have what i need.
And the joke is that i always use the method get_data(), shame on me